# ORA-01722: invalid number with Gson - GsonBuilder

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, gson

I am converting all entities to JSON using Gson. I am using the Oracle 11g database, and when I open dialog the following exception occurs when I want to convert:

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-01722: número no válido

at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy321.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1698)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:832)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2094)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:61)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:678)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1801)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:524)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:212)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:520)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:125)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:605)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:584)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:539)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:519)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.EventHandler$Listener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:273)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$EventListenerWrapper.processEvent(UIComponent.java:1579)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:43)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl._traverseListenerList(ApplicationImpl.java:2493)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:586)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:616)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:336)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:336)
at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:336)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.injection.InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(InjectionAwareApplicationWrapper.java:148)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:84)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.render(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:111)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at util.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.executeChain(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:91)
at util.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And how do I convert using the following code?

```java
builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.FACTORY)
    .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC)
    .serializeNulls();
gson2 = builder.create();
this.setJson(gson2.toJson(obj));
```

I don't use native SQL queries before executing.